# unable to use global variable while calling from button in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, combobox, global

I am unable to use global variable (count_task) in my label which I have returned from a function. I have globally declared this variable. While calling this function with code it gives result but while calling through button it doesn't work.

```py
global count_task

combo_user=ttk.Combobox(users_Frm,font=('arial',12),state='readonly')
combo_user['values']=(User_list_return())
combo_user.place(x=10,y=40,width=80,height=32)

user_tasks_lbl=Label(users_Frm,text="",font=('arial,bold',12),bg="#008B8B")
user_tasks_lbl.place(x=50,y=83, )
user_tasks_lbl['text']=count_task

user_tasks_show_Btn=Button(users_Frm, text="Show detail", 
                           command=toplevel, font=("arial,bold,10"))
user_tasks_show_Btn.place(x=180,y=40,width=150)

def user_task_count():
        global count_task
        count_task=dbf_user_task_count(combo_user.get())
        return count_task

user_tasks_sel_Btn=Button(users_Frm, text="Go", 
                          command=user_task_count, font=("arial,bold,10"))
user_tasks_sel_Btn.place(x=100,y=40,width=50)
```

Comment: Hello! you are declaring global variables wrong please [read](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables) here to understand better. Also, can you elaborate on why you are trying to save `combo_user` value to a variable with `.get()` when you can just simply use the same value anywhere in the code with `combo_user.get()`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. While using combo_user outside the home() module I get error and hence I had to declare all such variables as global but here I have corrected my code since here global variable is not required. Though in case of count_task I need to do this in order to use it outside this function.

Comment: I have gone through the guidelines about global variables. But I am still unable to use count_task outside this function. Please correct my code if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `global` when you declare count_task:

`count_task = 0` at the begining of your script.

Then the function `user_task_count` does not need to report any thing because it is used as a `command`argument, ie a callback to be exectuded when the associated button is clicked.

```
def user_task_count():
        global count_task
        count_task=dbf_user_task_count(combo_user.get())
        # nothing you can return to the button
```

What you wrote is simply a function that count the number of time button user_tasks_sel_Btn is clicked. Not sure this is what you want to do?